# Where did style related rules go in jshint?

Tags: jshint

It seems the team behind `jshint`, decided to remove all style related rules/options [(read more about it here)](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/releases/tag/2.5.0). like:

- smarttabs
- indent
- nomen

and a couple of others. Is there a way I can reactivate them?

Comment: Did you mean JSHint or Lint? (You initially had a jslint tag but mentioned jshint in the question.) Seems difficult to believe either did that intentionally. [Crockford mentioned removing support for a ton of stuff, including nomen](https://plus.google.com/118095276221607585885/posts/aBLU9y4Fd4z), but [hasn't made an edit in 7 months](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint) afaict. Even there he doesn't mention `indent`. And `smarttabs` is [just JS*H*int](http://jshint.com/docs/faq/), right? So I'm assuming you meant JSHint, though I don't see them being removed in 10 seconds of googling.

Comment: @ruffin you're right I must have subconsciously tagged it wrong, I found the answer I'll post it in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through more reading in [a git commit](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/commit/4035fef1af4ef426e9dc99918ca3aac0ce44b784) of `jshint` it seems that the team behind is recommending [`jscs`](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs) (javascript code style checker).

There `mikesherov`says:

> JSCS formats whitespace so that JSHint can do the hard work of catching real errors for you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Good catch. Looks like their [docs online](http://jshint.com/docs/faq/) are lagging behind. Interesting to offload that to another tool.